# Java: calculating the bearing between two Points on a 2D plane

Tags: java, angle

I am using this code to find the angle between two `Point` objects:

```
private float getAngle(Point targetPoint, Point centerPoint){
    // north = 90; south = 270; west = 180; east = 0; 
    // but in my method west = 0 and east = 180
    double theta = Math.atan2(targetPoint.y - centerPoint.y, targetPoint.x - centerPoint.x);
    float angle = (float) Math.toDegrees(theta);

    if(angle < 0){
        angle += 360;
    }
    return angle;
}
```

where `centerPoint` is : [160, 160] 
and `targetPoints` are: 
1 - [x=160,y=80], 2- [x=80,y=160], 3 - [x=240,y=160], 4 - [x=160,y=240].

I assume that 1 should be 90° , 2 - 180° , 3 - 0° and 4 - 270°

However I get this:

```
angle between robLoc java.awt.Point[x=160,y=160] and p java.awt.Point[x=160,y=80] is 90.0
angle between robLoc java.awt.Point[x=160,y=160] and p java.awt.Point[x=80,y=160] is 0.0
angle between robLoc java.awt.Point[x=160,y=160] and p java.awt.Point[x=240,y=160] is 180.0
angle between robLoc java.awt.Point[x=160,y=160] and p java.awt.Point[x=160,y=240] is 270.0
```

How can I tune the calculation method in order to obtain:
2 - 0° and 3 - 180° ?

Like on this picture:

[image]

Comment: you should change your centerpoint to 160,160

Comment: @user2539738 yes, you are right, thank you. Originally it is 160,160. I made an error while writing this question.

Comment: your assumptions are incorrect.  to go FROM (160,80) TO (160,160) you head north (90° as you indicate).  To go FROM (80,160) TO (160,160) you go east, (0°) similarly, from 3 to origin is west (180°) and then from 4 to origin is south (270°)

Comment: @user2539738 according to these assumptions, shouldn't the heading from 4 to origin be north (0) and from 1 to origin south (270)?

Comment: let's subtract 160 from everything.  to go from (0,-80) to (0,0) you head north.  since you're at negative 80. also north is 90, not 270 according to the diagram

Comment: @user2539738 you are right, thank you!